# using vuejs with handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, vuejs2

I am using vue in my project and the backend is rendered using handlebars by express.
the issue is both vue and handlebars are using the same template syntax which is {{ }}
How can I escape the double curly braces in handlebars so it will be picked by vue in the front end ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't supports custom delimiters. You may have these options:

1) Instead of using Handlebars.js switch to Mustache.js (his "older brother") and then:

```
Mustache.tags = ['<%', '%>'];
```

2) Or tweak Vue.js:

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['<%', '%>'];
```

or

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}']
});
```

3) Start using *.vue files, that way you wont need to define custom delimiters

Answer (score 3):

With handlebars it is very easy to escape the default delimiters. So instead of `{{ item.name }}` just write `\{{ item.name }}`. Handlebars will not replace this but Vue.js will.

Answer (score -3):

Another answer will be using helpers

```
exports.curlyBracesOpen = function() {
    return '{{ ';
};
exports.curlyBracesClose = function() {
    return ' }}';
};
```

and then use it like this

```
{{{curlyBracesOpen}}} item {{{curlyBracesClose}}}
```